# How conditionally disable MVC controllers, while API controllers remain active in .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have both MVC and API controllers an a .NET 5 project.

API controllers respond at `/api` path

MVC controllers respond at root `/`

How to conditionally disable MVC controllers, while API controllers remain active in .NET 5 ?

A request to the disabled MVC should then return either 404 or 410 response.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (Configuration["MVC"] == "false")
  {
     ???
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you distinguishing MVC vs API controllers?

Comment: do you have any metadata to identify which controllers are for MVC and which are for API ? Usually the api controllers will have `[ApiControllerAttribute]` but that's not required, or its actions usually are targeted by attribute routing but that's not required again. With the requirement of returning `404`, of course the controllers can be completely removed but for `410`, you may have to use middlewares or filters to handle the requests (intercepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are multiple ways to deal with this but the simplest one is using a middleware to short-circuit the request, it can be simple like this:

```
//inside the Startup.Configure
//this should be placed at the beginning of the pipeline
//or at least before the mvc middleware
app.Use((context,next) => {
     if(Configuration["MVC"] == "false" && 
        !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")){
         context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
     return next();
});
```

Note that the code above is inside `Startup` class which usually defines a `Configuration` property of `IConfiguration`.